# How to avoid MySQL error 1442 after update trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to build a simple referral system in MySQL, not PHP.
When an user earns points, his referrer has to automatically earn 10% of that points too, and so on while points are greater than 1.
Example:
Jim earns 20,
so his referrer John earns 2,
so his referrer Mark doesn't earns because his part is 0.2

This is the code:

```
drop table if exists account;
create table test.account(
username char(100) PRIMARY KEY,
points int,
referrer char(100)
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_general_cs;

drop trigger if exists updater;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updater AFTER UPDATE ON account FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @points_to_referrer=(NEW.points-OLD.points)*0.1;
IF(@points_to_referrer>1)THEN
    UPDATE account SET points=points+@points_to_referrer WHERE username=OLD.referrer;
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO `test`.`account` (`username`, `points`, `referrer`) VALUES ('john', '10', 'mark');
INSERT INTO `test`.`account` (`username`, `points`, `referrer`) VALUES ('mark', '10', 'jim');
INSERT INTO `test`.`account` (`username`, `points`, `referrer`) VALUES ('jim', '10', 'john');
```

...and this is a comand sample:

```
UPDATE `test`.`account` SET `points`='30' WHERE `username`='jim';
```

This command triggers the 1442 error instead of updates because it seems to be an infinite loop.
Can I force the execution of this code by setting any system option, possibly in my.ini?
Or are there other ways to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You better use a before update trigger.

Comment: Same error with BEFORE.

Comment: I guess you can not use update on an update trigger, but you can use an other table and an event (never used) for that

`create table ref_earnings (
    username char(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    points int,
    given tinyint
) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

And you can insert to that table on update trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a table (account) where the trigger is invoked:

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Doing so will generate Error 1442:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'account' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

---

**Solution**: if all you want is, to set a field's value before update, you can do so using `BEFORE UPDATE ON` trigger and using `NEW` operator:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updater;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updater BEFORE UPDATE ON account FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @points_to_referrer=(NEW.points-OLD.points)*0.1;
    IF(@points_to_referrer > 1)THEN
        SET NEW.points = NEW.points + @points_to_referrer;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You can set the field values with `BEFORE UPDATE/INSERT ON` as they haven't been updated/inserted yet. All you need to do is set the `NEW.<field>` (all the values for current row are accessible using `NEW.<field_name>`) to whatever you want to.